# Lost bitcoins on smartphone after resetting it, although I backed it up before

Tags: bitcoin-wallet-app, wallet-recovery

I lost my bitcoins after resetting my android smartphone. Is it possible to get hold of my lost bitcoins?? I did back up my smartphone before I reset it. So after I reset the phone all my apps were there including the bitcoin wallet( by Bitcoin Wallet Developers), although the wallet was now empty.  Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Did you backup your apps data as well? for example using Titanium Backup? If you didn't backup your wallet and didn't backup your app's data I'm not sure it'd be easy to restore the wallet.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Menu->Safety->Restore wallet and select the backup file and enter the password you encrypted with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I didn't however back up my bitoin wallet. I backed up my smortphone data with apps to my google accounts. Is it still possible to get hold of my lost bitcoins??

Comment: @Magnus Not unless the wallet exists in the data backup/